# Java reading from Standard in using Scanner giving wrong results

Tags: java, parsing, input, java.util.scanner, system.in

I am using netbeans.

I am trying to read standard in or arguments using Scanner. However whenever I try to display something, I get something completely different.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println(input);
```

So, for example if the preset command line argument is "Awesome!"
I want it to print out Awesome! But I get some long gibberish such as :

> java.util.Scanner[delimiters=\p{javaWhitespace}+][position=0][match valid=false][need input=false][source closed=false][skipped=false][group separator=\,][decimal separator=.][positive prefix=][negative prefix=\Q-\E][positive suffix=][negative suffix=][NaN string=\Q�\E][infinity string=\Q∞\E]

Comment: so i tried using
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = s.nextLin();
    
   System.out.println(input);
And it still won't print out my command line argument

Comment: Okay, anyway, I used command prompt to compile and run instead of an IDE like Net Beans. Don`t know why Net Beans gives me a weird answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here `Scanner` is the class name, a is the name of object, `new` keyword is used to allocate the memory and `System.in` is the input stream. you can use following methods of Scanner class (for your case its string) :

1. nextInt to input an integer
2. nextFloat to input a float
3. nextLine to input a string

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {

       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
       String user_value = in.nextLine();        
       System.out.println(user_value);
   }
   ```

Comment: I try to do this in net beans with the command line arguments and nothing gets printed?

Comment: @GreatShark - just copy above code and paste inside the main method. (You should import `java.util.Scanner;`) . Then run it and type something in console and press enter. -exactly it should works!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code you should use:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class InputTesting { 

    public static void main( String[] args ) { 
        Scanner input = new Scanner ( System.in ); 
        String str1; 
        System.out.println("Input string: "); 
        str1 = input.next(); 
        System.out.println( str1 ); 
    }
}
```